# Calling [HTTPPost] from Javascript ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, http-post

I am using a method in my controller which imports data from an API. This method I am wanted to be called from two locations. First the view (currently working) and secondly a javascript function.

Start of controller method:

```
[ActionName("ImportRosters")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PerformImportRosterData(int id, int? actualLength, int? rosterLength)
    {
        var authenticator = Authenticator(id);
        var rosters = authenticator.Api().RosterData().ToDictionary(x => x.Id);

        var databaseRosterDatas = SiteDatabase.DeputyRosterData.Where(x => x.SiteID == id)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Id);
```

Javascript Function:

```
$("#btnDeputyRunNowUpdate").click(function() {
    $("#btnRunDeputyNow").modal("hide");
    ActualLength = $("#actualRunLength").val();
    RosterLength = $("#rosterRunLength").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/deputy/PerformImportRosterData",
        data: { SiteIDRoster, ActualLength, RosterLength }
    });
    SiteIDRoster = null;
    location.reload();
    $("#btnRunDeputyNow").modal("hide");
    toast.show("Import Successful", 3000);
});
```

All values are being set but i am getting a 404 error on the url line
*POST https://example.org/deputy/PerformImportRosterData 404 ()*

I need a way to be able to call this c# method from both html and JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done if you will modify the URL in your AJAX. It should look something like

```
url: '<%= Url.Action("YourActionName", "YourControllerName") %>'
```

or

```
url: @Url.Action("YourActionName", "YourControllerName")
```

one more thing, I don't see if you do anything with the result of the call. your script does not have success part

```
 success: function(data) {//do something with the return}
```

and would be very helpful to have error handler in your call.
full example on how AJAX should look like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "target.aspx",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "html",
  success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
   $("#container").html(data);
    alert("Local success callback.");
   },
   error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {
     alert("Local error callback.");
  },
  complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
     alert("Local completion callback.");
  }
})
```

For a good tutorial on AJAX read [this document](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/749ed588-b408-4a7e-94da-77549c00e803.aspx)

Change after Comment:
my current code is below:

```
$("#btnDeputyRunNowUpdate").click(function() {
    $("#btnRunDeputyNow").modal("hide");
    ActualLength = $("#actualRunLength").val();
    RosterLength = $("#rosterRunLength").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<%= Url.Action("PerformImportRosterData", "DeputyController") %>',
        data: { SiteIDRoster, ActualLength, RosterLength },

        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log("TESTHERE");

        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Noticed one more thing. Your parameters in the controller and AJAX do not match. Please try to replace your a few lines in your AJAX call with:

```
    url: "/deputy/PerformImportRosterData",
    data: { id: yourIDValue,  actualLength: youractualLengthValue,  
            rosterLength :yourrosterLengthValue }
```

remember to set all variable values in javascript , if they have no values set them = to null.

**Can you try copy paste code below**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/deputy/PerformImportRosterData",
    data: { SiteIDRoster:999, ActualLength:1, RosterLength:2 }
});
```

And let me know if it wall cause any errors.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I first tried your first url change and it gave this error
https://imgur.com/a/zZGOp
next i tried your second change and gave this error
https://imgur.com/a/qSVx5

my original example has been adapted to show the change

Comment: Can you please provide images and samples in some other way. I don't have ingur installed. Just simple screenshots uploaded to this site will do. Did you modified your code to have success and error?

Comment: I added both success and error. Imgur is a website which holds the photos, no need to install and I cannot upload images into comments. I have edited the original question but waiting for it to be 'peer reviewed'.
But in theory, the fist example you gave comes up with an error about experiemental decorators. the second giving a 400() error in the console

Comment: what is the extension of the page where you have your javascript?

Comment: Hello. I'm sorry I don't understand the question. I have checked all of the values and made sure they aren't null. url: '@Url.Action("/PerformImportRosterData", "Deputy")', is still coming back as a 404 error. I am calling this method from a js file which is talking to a controller called deputyController (but have tried deputy in url as) for a method called PerformImportRosterData. Hope this helps

Comment: Have tried without the forward slash in perform, using ImportRosters (the actionName), ensured the ajax and controller match

Comment: Any errors? How does it look like? Please post your current code

Comment: My current attempt looks like this            
url: '@Url.Action("PerformImportRosterData", "Deputy")', which is giving an error of https://example.org/deputy/@Url.Action (%22PerformImportRosterData%22,%20%22Deputy%22) 404 ()

Comment: Provided link leads to invalid page, please use images

Comment: both images of code and error are here. Cannot post direct links into comments to imgur it is https://imgur.com/a/sj8Vh

Comment: Ok, your page is not processing razor. most likely due to wrong extension. Please replace url to url: "/deputy/PerformImportRosterData", and try again

Comment: I have changed to that and same 404() error. that is the original url I began with

Comment: how is your data looks like?

Comment: siteIDRoster = 999 (int), actualLength = 1 (int), rosterLength = 2(int)

Answer (score 0):

After attempting to solve for a few days, I created a workaround by creating two methods for importing the data. one for the httpPost and the second for import calling from javascript.

Not a great solution but it works. Thanks for your help Yuri